# node_add in Queue, only inserts first 3 as front, rear and middle

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, logic, abstract-data-type

My insert function works fine for the empty queue, the queue with front and rear equal and one more. After that there seems to be a logic error. I only have 2 hours to submit this.

Ouput for testing ascending and descending

Testing the ascending queue
Inserting:  42 17 -12 9982 476 2912 -22 3291213 7782

Removing:   17 3291213 7782

Testing the descending queue
Inserting:  42 17 -12 9982 476 2912 -22 3291213 7782

Removing:   42 -22 7782

Testing the FIFO queue
Inserting:  42 17 -12 9982 476 2912 -22 3291213 7782

Removing:   42 17 -12 9982 476 2912 -22 3291213 7782

```
void que_insert( QueueADT queue, void *data ) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data= data;
    node *currNode;
                //currNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    currNode = queue->front;
    //cmp = &(queue->cmprFunc);
    if ( queue->front != NULL ) {
            if ( queue->cmprFunc == NULL ) {        //if the cmp_func is FIFO

                queue->rear->next = temp;
                queue->rear= temp;
                queue->rear->next=NULL;
                if ( queue->front == queue->rear ) {
                    currNode->next = temp;
                    queue->rear = temp;
                    temp->next= NULL;
                    }
            } else {

                while ( currNode->next != NULL ){
                    if (( (*(queue->cmprFunc))(currNode->next->data, temp->data) < 0 ) ||
                            ((*(queue->cmprFunc))(currNode->next->data, temp->data) == 0 ) ) {
                        temp->next = currNode->next;
                        currNode->next = temp;
                        break;

                    } else  {
                        currNode = currNode->next;
                        if (currNode->next != NULL )  {
                            currNode->next = temp;
                            queue->rear = temp;
                            temp->next = NULL;
                        }
                                            //exit_failure  
                    }
                }
                if ( queue->front == queue->rear ) {

                    if (( (*(queue->cmprFunc))(currNode->data, temp->data) < 0 ) ||
                            ((*(queue->cmprFunc))(currNode->data, temp->data) == 0 ) ) {
                            queue->rear = temp;
                            queue->front->next = queue->rear;
                            temp->next= NULL;
                        } else {
                            queue->front = temp;
                            temp->next = temp;

                        }
                    }
                //printf("Front is equal to next %i\n", (queue->front == queue->rear));
            }
    } else {                                                //( queue->front == NULL )
        queue->front = temp;
        queue->rear= queue->front;
        queue->front->next= queue->rear->next = NULL;

        }
    }
```

The compare function returns an int based on the following criteria:

```
*** < 0 a < b
 = 0    a == b
 > 0    a > b***
```

where ">" and "<" are dependent upon the data being compared

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node *next;
}node;


struct queueStruct {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int (*cmprFunc)(const void*a,const void*b);
    //size_t num;                               /* The compare function used for insert */
};

typedef struct queueStruct *QueueADT;       //typedef inserted for pointers, name is QueueADT

#define _QUEUE_IMPL_
#include "queueADT.h"

/// create a queue that is either sorted by cmp or FIFO
//function with two void
QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {

    QueueADT new;
    new = (QueueADT)malloc(sizeof(struct queueStruct));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
        new->cmprFunc = NULL;

    } else {
        new->cmprFunc = cmp;
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
    }

    return ( new );
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the new node at the end or at the beggining of the list?

Comment: I will usually add the node at the beginning if First in first out, but if the compare(currNode, tempData) returns negative then it goes before the currNode. If compare(currNode, tempData) is positive then it should move the back of the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *que_insert*:

```
void que_insert( QueueADT queue, void *data ) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data= data;
    node *currNode, *prevNode = NULL;

    currNode = queue->front;

    if(currNode == NULL){
        //first node to add
        temp->next = NULL;
        queue->front = temp;
        queue->rear = temp;

        return;
    }

    while(currNode != NULL){
        if( /* comparison is negative */ ){
            temp->next = currNode;
            if(prevNode != NULL){
                prevNode->next = temp;
            }
            else{
                queue->front = temp;
            }

            return;
        }

        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }

    //add to the end
    prevNode->next = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
    queue->rear = temp;
}
```

Comment: I am reading this but I have to submit now, This might be more clean than my approach. Leave POSITIVE!

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem is with this line:

```
if ( queue->front == queue->rear ) {
```

You have already assigned the value of `temp` to `queue->rear` a couple of lines up, so this if test will never evaluate to true. You would need to rearrange where the assignment happens, or save the old value for later testing, set a flag variable before you do the assignment. As this is homework, you should try to fix this yourself.